# Fill for external SVG file in React

Tags: reactjs, svg

It doesn't seem to be possible so far to control the SVG elements that are stored in a separate file. I thought maybe with WebPack and npm modules it should be possible yet can't find a simple or convenient solution. Is it possible to import element like this?

```
import icon from "./icons/user.svg"

<icon fill="red" />
```

I don't understand why it is so hard to work with SVG here, or why can't I find enough information on the topic. Maybe I am doing this wrong? Are there better ways to manage a lot of icons for a React website? I need will be using quite a few, like social networks stuff and similar.

Comment: You can simply output `svg` as `html`.

Comment: @Sulthan can I change the colors that way?

Comment: You can always use styles to change colors.

Comment: @Sulthan Please give an example of the code. I have a lot of SVG icons and simply adding them to the App code might make a lot of useless code. I want it to stay clear but flexible.

Comment: Start with https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-inline-svg

Answer (score 4):

If you use Create React App, then the easiest solution is to import SVG as a React component

```
import { ReactComponent as User } from './icons/user.svg';

const View = () => <User />;
```

See more in the docs: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files#adding-svgs

Answer (score 2):

Include an external SVG image with four lines of code:

```
<svg>
  <use xlinkHref={'/images/logo.svg#Version-2'}>
  </use>
</svg>
```

In this case the SVG image "logo.svg" will have an ID in it named: "Version-2". The part after the hash "#" maps to an ID in the SVG image that must of course exist.

Answer (score 0):

This answered my question:

https://github.com/gilbarbara/react-inlinesvg

1. Embed the CSS in the SVG document

   - Can't use your CSS preprocessors (LESS, SASS)
   - Can't target parent elements (button hover, etc.)
   - Makes maintenance difficult
2. Link to a CSS file in your SVG document

   - Sharing styles with your HTML means duplicating paths across your project, making maintenance a pain
   - Not sharing styles with your HTML means extra HTTP requests (and likely duplicating paths between different SVGs)
   - Still can't target parent elements
   - Your SVG becomes coupled to your external stylesheet, complicating reuse.
3. Embed the SVG in your HTML

   - Bloats your HTML
   - SVGs can't be cached by browsers between pages.
   - A maintenance nightmare

**But there's an alternative that sidesteps these issues: load the SVG with an XHR request and then embed it in the document. That's what this component does.**

I decided to use inline-svg for react, but I was also told about another method wrapping SVG into an object. I don't know anything about that as I haven't tried yet, but I'll list it just to fill up the collection:

```
<object>
  <embed src="/static/filename.svg">
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to keep the code simple and treat *SVG* as a *HTML*. This way you avoid resizing/stretch/config and host of other *SVG/React* issues.

Create a generic Icon component,

```
const Icon = ({ name, children }) => (
    <svg className={`icon icon-${name}`}>
        {children}
    </svg>
)
```

Create the *user* Icon component,

```
const UserIcon = ({ fill }) => (
    // fill your inner svg code here, set fill to the correct react node
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I looks a bit struggling, but here is the best solution I could end up with : Use webpack `file-loader` to get the url of your svg and use it as a css mask on which you can apply a background color and some sizing options  :

```
const name = 'chevron-up';
const size = 16;
const url = require(`!file-loader!../../../vendor/my-icons/icons/${name}.svg`);

return
  <span style={{
    height: size,
    width: size,
    display: 'inline-block',
    backgroundColor: backgroundColor || 'black',
    WebkitMask: `url('${url}') no-repeat 50% 50% / cover`,
    mask: `url('${url}') no-repeat 50% 50% / cover`,
  }} />
;
```

It has a couple compatibility isssues for now, but it is supported by most latest browsers. So I guess we should embrace the future my friend !

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/mask